# How do I upgrade m.2 ssd to larger m.2 NVMe ssd with one slot (Laptop)

Tags: ssd, upgrade, disk-image, disk-cloning, m.2

I just bought an m.2 ssd of greater volume and didnt realize i cannot have both of them plugged in. I struggled founding the answer on net.
So the question is how do i migrate/clone, my current ssd to newer ssd. Note that I am running my OS there, new ssd size 512GB, old ssd size = 128GB, hdd size 1TB (free 590GB).

Comment: Is there another storage (like HDD) available that can be used with either SSD at the same time? How much space is there on the other storage? Is it encrypted? How big is the old SSD? What is the OS on the old SSD? What is the partition layout? the filesystem(s)? Can you boot some live Linux distro from CD/DVD/USB?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowki Yes i do have another hdd(right now have 2 connected old ssd and hdd ), enough to fit my old ssd 8x, dont know, 3x my ssd, Windows, i never changed anything,ntfs,dont have experience with that,

Comment: @Moab: Note that's for SATA M.2 devices only; chances are OP has an NVMe M.2 disk.

Comment: I actually do have NVMe - updated the title

Comment: Could you add the sizes of the other disks to the Q please?

Comment: Clonezilla Live should do the trick. As mentioned, you will need an USB-drive to store the image into. See: https://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/01_Save_disk_image